resolve the DUPIRE Forward PDE
I want to implement the "Dupire forward PDE". I will use this PDE to calibrate a parametric local volatility model. Could you recommend an article or link that explains concretely how I can proceed?
Dupire Forward PDE :


what have you tried so far?

The classic Black ans scholes PDE

The direct application of Dupire PDE to market data is dangerous due to numerical stability issues (that can give nonsense results). More pratical approaches are illustrated in Richard White's paper https://quant.opengamma.io/Local-Volatility-OpenGamma.pdf or in Gatheral's writing.

@nbbo2 I know this paper. I'm looking for a paper that explains the implementation of PDE
